# cephfs quota can't work

Tags: filesystems, quota, ceph

ALL:

I'm using cephfs with quota limit.

- use ceph-fuse mount

  `ceph-fuse      fuse.ceph-fuse  105G  5.6G  100G   6% /ceph`
- create quota limit

  `setfattr -n ceph.quota.max_bytes -v 100000000  /ceph/rc`
- show quota limit

`[root@localhost ~]# getfattr  -n ceph.quota.max_bytes  /ceph/rc
    getfattr: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
    # file: ceph/rc
    ceph.quota.max_bytes="100000000"`

- try to create largger files 

  `[root@locahost rc]# dd if=/dev/zero  of=1G.img bs=1G count=1
  1+0 records in
  1+0 records out
  1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 31.0612 s, 34.6 MB/s
  [root@localhost rc]# du -sh * 
  1.0G    1G.img`

---

Doen't it work with cephfs quota ???

anybody can give me same sugestion？

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly same problem, resolved using `--client-quota` option when mounting with `ceph-fuse`.

```
ceph-fuse -m ip address:6789 --client-quota /XXX
```